# Raspberries too wet in muffin

Tags: texture, muffins, raspberries

I made white chocolate raspberry muffins the other day after being inspired by these muffins at a cafe near work. They were absolutely delicious (warmed up in a microwave for 5 seconds), however, the only problem was that the raspberries were a little bit too wet inside of the muffins that I made. I used fresh raspberries for it. Should I be using frozen raspberries or what other things can I try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve made muffins with fresh raspberries.

Increase the amount of flour you’re using, to help absorb the extra moisture. (I add somewhere in the range of 20-30g for 12 normal-size muffins.)

Cut the berries up into smaller pieces, put the pieces on paper towels, and cover with more paper towels. This soaks up some of the juice, and distributes it better throughout the batter.

Be as gentle as possible when mxing them in.

Frozen berries are going to be leakier than fresh.

Answer (score 4):

Raspberries are going to leak a little and stain the batter of any muffin they are put into.  Muffins with whole berries are going to have reduced shelf life due to this.

Frozen raspberries would be even more leaky, as the freezing and thawing will soften them.

To make a raspberry muffin, you have to accept that raspberry is very moist, so you cannot overload the muffin; the have to be used with a moderate amount of restraint.

Dusting the raspberries with flour (from the main quantity of flour in the recipe) before mixing them into the batter may help form a barrier, although I wouldn't count on a dramatic change in outcome.  I have not personally tried this, though.

If you don't mind a completely reddish muffin, you can puree some or all of the berries, and use them as a substitute for some or all of the water or milk in the recipe, as they are about 87% water to start with.  This will allow you to balance the liquid level.